# Ghost click on lower-right corner

Tags: mouse, touchpad, touchscreen

I'm dual booting my ASUS Taichi21 with windows 10 and ubuntu 15.04 for a week or so. It was all working perfectly, but last night my mouse cursor
started randomly clicking the lower right corner of the screen in totally random intervals (which, in an application wit a scrolling bar, makes it scroll down a little bit, or makes my cursor go out of the field I'm typing in. Its making everything rather unusable)

I've tried both unplugging my mouse and disabling the touchpad, to no avail.

I've tried updating to ubuntu 15.10, but the issue persists.

This laptop has a touchscreen on the back of the regular screen, which I can't get to work with ubuntu, so I disabled it. However, I found out that if I touch the back of my screen it still reads the touch as if it was mirroring my screen upside-down. I tried to clean the back of the screen in case this was being caused by finger marks or the like, but it didn't solve the problem as well.

This doesn't happen in windows, and was not happening in ubuntu until last night. I hadn't installed anything new prior to that happening either.

The frequency in which this happens changes a lot, but I can't correlate it with anything except that it happens more often when I'm actually moving the mouse. It also happens when I'm only typing (with touchpad disabled) though. I'm assuming the OS is getting some "fake positive" inputs from the mouse, but I honestly have no idea what's going on.

Should I try reinstalling mouse drivers like I'd do in windows? My ubuntu experience is pretty limited

TL;DR: Mouse cursor randomly started clicking lower-right of the screen in random intervals and even disabling it doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Just solved the issue. Went to System Settings -> Screen Display and checked the "Mirror Displays" box. For some reason the thing never happened again after that.